# Real Dilemma when using Sessions, Cookies in Yii

Tags: session, cookies, yii, setstate

I have set sessions for my properties/methods in WebUser like following

```
public function getRole(){
$user = $this->loadUser(Yii::app()->user->id);
$this->setState('roleId', $user->roles_id);
return $user->roles_id;
}
```

In the config, I have set autostart sessions to 'true', cookieMode to 'only'. I understand that when i 'setState', the cookie with the same name is also created along with the session variable. Currently I am calling these variables using `Yii::app()->user->roleId;`

My question is this:
a) To utilize from the cookies and/or the session variables already set, should i call them using `Yii::app()->request->cookies['roleId']; or Yii::app()->session['roleId']?`

b) Will calling `Yii::app()->user->roleId` get me the value if it is already set as Cookie or Session instead of running the whole method again?

I appreciate your support!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would only use sessions for that. Cookies can be easily tampered with and a user could probably assign himself another role id. Session is somewhat safer.

Use your WebUsers `getRole()` for that, which caches it in the session like you have above. This is fine. Just put a check at the top, if there is a session var `roleId` instantly return it. If not, load the user and get it there like you already have.

Comment: Thank you, that seems like a good solution. But i have already allowed cookies. Do you think i should disable the cookies in total?. What happens when i am using both the sessions and the cookie and someone tampered the cookie?. Where should i actually use cookies then?

Comment: No not at all. I just meant not to save critical variables in a cookie. Having cookies on is fine, and of course you need it on at least to store the session ID, otherwise your sessions wouldn't work.

Comment: This is what i did. please check: 
 
    public function getRoleId(){
    if($this->hasState("roleId")){ return $this->getState("roleId");}
    $user = $this->loadUser(Yii::app()->user->id);
    $this->setState('roleId', $user->roles_id);
    return $user->roles_id;
    }

Comment: Do you think i should check if the cookie is also set before or this is it. Thanks for the patience..

Comment: There is no need to check the cookie. If there is no cookie, there would be no session and therefore `hasState()` would be false.